# How to change the default zoom level of a map in Geodjango's admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, openstreetmap, geodjango

I've been looking into GeoDjango recently, I'm struggling to customize the default zoom level of the openstreet map displaying in my admin section.
Below is what I have tried but with no effect, please assist.

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin

class LocationAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    default_zoom = 5

admin_site.register(ReferenceSpaceLocation, LocationAdmin)
```

- My model

  ```
  class ReferenceSpaceLocation(models.Model):

      geometry = models.GeometryField()
  ```

[image]

Comment: Can you check the source code and see what is being passed into `map.setCenter` method ?

Comment: Also, which django version are you using ?

Comment: Here is the value :  geodjango_geometry.map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 4); I'm using Django version 3.0.3.

Comment: Can you try with a higher zoom like `10` and see if it is taking impact on the zoom or not? default is actually `4`

Comment: Can you include your model definition, and the line where you register your model with your admin interface.

Comment: If we look at your image, seems everything is ok. On your image you can see: 
`Scale = 1:14K`
It is equal to `default_zoom = 15`. It means your default works, please check it again.

I just tried with `Django==2.1.15` and it works correctly, `default_*` values applied.

But please note, `default_*` settings are only applied for empty fields. If the field is not empty - then bounding fit applied, not default_zoom

Answer (score 4):

#### Your specific case

The default value for `point_zoom` with `OSMGeoAdmin` is 14 which is what your's seems to be at the moment. Try overwriting `point_zoom` in `LocationAdmin`. As is explained below, this should work if you are using `PointField` or `MultiPointField`.

#### How the zoom level will be determined:

The default zoom level will depend upon a few different things:

- If there is no data to display (e.g. you're looking at a new instance), the `default_zoom` will be used. This can be set as follows:

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    default_zoom = 5
```

- If we are using the fields `PointField` or `MultiPointField` then then it looks like the `point_zoom` value will be used instead of the `default_zoom`. This can be set as follows:

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    point_zoom = 10
```

- Otherwise, the zoom level will be set automatically based on the bounds of the data.

#### Why is this the case?

If you look in the source code, you'll see the following in the js file that run's that admin view:

```
// django/contrib/gis/templates/gis/admin/openlayers.js

    var wkt = document.getElementById('{{ id }}').value;
    if (wkt){
        ...

        // Zooming to the bounds.
        {{ module }}.map.zoomToExtent(admin_geom.geometry.getBounds());
        if ({{ module }}.is_point){
            {{ module }}.map.zoomTo({{ point_zoom }});
        }
    } else {
        {% localize off %}
        {{ module }}.map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat({{ default_lon }}, {{ default_lat }}), {{ default_zoom }});
        {% endlocalize %}
    }
```

This means that:

- if we are dealing with no data, then we are in the else clause of the above code. Right at the end of the line, it can be seen `default_zoom` is used.
- If we are using the fields `PointField` or `MultiPointField` then `{{module}}.is_point` is true, and as can be seen `point_zoom` is used.
- If neither of the above is the case, we can see the following is executed: `zoomToExtent(admin_geom.geometry.getBounds())`.

Comment: Hey Time , thanks for response. I have tried your solution but doesn't have any effect on the map.  Here is how I registered my model in the admin admin_site.register(ReferenceSpaceLocation, LocationAdmin)

Comment: @christiannyembo do you notice any effect when using an empty field? Could you post what `ReferenceSpaceLocation` looks like please?

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm certain you have identified the problem. I've tested it and found your solution works. Can I suggest that you update the beginning of your answer with a clear example of how `LocationAdmin` should include `point_zoom`. It might help others.

Comment: @MattRowbum thanks for the suggestion, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Tim I've tried different solutions suggested but, still nothing changes. I have updated the screenshot of my admin section, maybe it could help. Thanks.